# JS/Mongo - Storing APi keys from other website

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, api-key

I am making a website (A) which is kind of a dashboard when user could see all their data from different websites (xyz) they are registered too. To access their data on those websites (xyz), they'll have to save their API keys they get on websites (xyz) in my website's database (A). Those keys are read-only keys meaning my app would just access data and not modify from the other website, but still those give access to private information and therefor should be secured.

What's is the best secure way to store these keys in website (A) database ? I guess Hash is no good cause I won't be able to use the key as no way to get back to the original key through hashing. But then, how would there be a 2-way encryption that is secure ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should ensure the database is [encrypted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-encryption-at-rest/), the [transit is encrypted](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/), and you have appropriate [access control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control) (both via API and direct to the database). I would suggest against anything else as it'd be redundant or [through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), both of which increase attack vectors. Focus on doing the four things (storage, transit, access, and auth) right.

Comment: This question is very broad, and won't get much response. @Vox is right, what you are doing is risky, and you should at least make sure things are encrypted and secured.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am normally working with Meteor + MongoDb. For me the question is not that broad. I got to store the APi keys of people who have an account on my website for them to access the data on the other website (like a dashboard that access other website). Question is how to make this safe ? Is "simple" meteor with mongo enough ?